# How to get only date after subtraction of two date field

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to have subtraction of two data fields and the result in days. But I'm having time also at the output. How do I get only days not the time.

Here is my code:

```
class ItemTable(models.Model):
    expdate = models.DateField("EXP Date", null=True, blank=True)

 def days_to_exp(self):
    if self.expdate:
        now = datetime.date.today()
        exp = str(self.expdate - now)

        if exp > "1":
            return exp
        elif exp < "1" and exp > "0":
            return "Today"
        else:
            return "Expired"
```

output:

12 days, 0:00:00,
4 days, 0:00:00... etc

I just want the result as:
 12 days,
 4 days..... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of subtracting one `datetime.date` from another is a `timedelta` object. You can access the `.days` attribute of that `timedelta` object to get what you're after.

```
> today = datetime.now().date()
> tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)
> (tomorrow - today).days
1
> (today - tomorrow).days
-1
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I was missing the .days the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

Result of subtraction between `datetime.date` instances is an object with type of `datetime.timedelta` that represents a duration not `datetime.date` nor `datetime.datatime`. you can get how long a `timedelta` is by accessing it's `.days` property.

for example:

```
result = now().today() - (now()+timedelta(days=10))
assert(result.days==10)
```

Comment: thank you. it was confusing first your answer gave me a clear idea. adding only .days gave me the answer

Comment: it's your welcome, if my answer has helped you please mark it as correct and upvote it. thanks.